# Broken paths to images in Symfony2 Dev environment

Tags: symfony

After succesfully publishing my bundle, dev environment is broken.

[image: broken symfony2]

To publish my assets i did :

`php console assets:install --symlink --relative /home/bitnami/stack/frameworks/symfony/web`

`php console assetic:dump`

`php console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Images are referenced to : 
/symfony/web/bundles/webprofiler/images/profiler/logo_symfony_profiler.png

Comment: Is the virtual host configured to follow symlinks? (like FollowSymlinks directive on apache)

Comment: @ibtarek Yep, the symlinks are not a problem in the production environment.

Comment: Is this the dev or prod environment? What url are you accessing?

Comment: @Squazic is dev environment through app_dev.php

Comment: Can you just try : `$ php app/console assets:install web --symlink` then `$ php/app console cache:clear`

Comment: correcting Touki: `$ php app/console cache:clear` than it works like a charm :)

Comment: @Touki Could you post your solution as an answer? It worked for me. Thanks :)